# String sent from controller gets separated when being processed to HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to send validation rules as string from the controller to input element. The string is sent correctly but it is not rendered correctly (you can see on the snippet below that it separates "Field is required" to "Field" is="" required="").

This is what I get after HTML is rendered:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control valid" id="Code" name="Code" 
     value="INDiamnana" 
     data-rule-required="true" 
     data-msg-required="Field" is="" required="" 
     aria-required="true">
```

In the controller I build the string in a way similiar to this:

```
 stringBuilder.Append("data-rule-required=true");
 stringBuilder.AppendLine();
 stringBuilder.Append("data-msg-required=Field is required" );
```

And I specify in my razor:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control valid" 
 id="..." name="..." 
 value="..." 
 @Model.ValidationRules />
```

@Model.ValidationRules is  a string of the format

> "data-rule-required=true data-msg-required=Field is required"

Does anyone know how to explicitly say that I want my string non-separable? 
Or maybe I am doing it all wrong and I should send the string in different way ?

Comment: I think what you mostly need is escaped quotes inside your string

stringBuilder.Append("data-rule-required=\"true\""); because it's really hard to tell what you mean by non-separable

Comment: On the first snippet I have posted, there is the data-msg-required ="..." , you can see how it separates my message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the HTML attribute value has spaces, which is invalid. The first word, `Field`, is interpreted as the value, whereas `is` and `required` are interpreted as other attributes. Hence `=""` is added after them by the browser.

To solve this you need to wrap the attribute values in double quotes:

```
stringBuilder.Append("data-rule-required=\"true\"");
stringBuilder.Append("data-msg-required=\"Field is required\"");
```

Also note that your use of `AppendLine()` in the stringBuilder is redundant. HTML doesn't care about whitespace. All it does is make your code more verbose.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control valid" id="Code" name="Code" value="INDiamnana" data-rule-required="&quot;true&quot;data-msg-required=&quot;Field" is="" required&quot;="" aria-required="true"> is what i get as a result.

Comment: Razor is HTMLEncoding the output. Append the value as a `HtmlString`, or use `@Html.Raw()`

Comment: @Html.Raw() does not seem to do the trick. And about HtmlString I am not completely certain that I am doing it correctly because when I append it, it adds it as a value of the input not as attribute

Comment: That sounds like you may be appending in the wrong place. Glad you got it working though

Comment: I didn't say that I got it working but I am working on it. If you still have suggestions, let me know.

Comment: Apologies - I read 'Html.Raw() seemed to do the trick'. What is the output of the above code now?

Comment: I tried using Html.Raw, HtmlEncode(), HtmlDecode(), HtmlAttributeEncode(), non of them seemd to give the correct answer. So I tried to separate it as variables and not directly apply it to the input field as @Model.ValidationRules. The strange thing is that when i separated it as a variable HTML.Raw() **DID**  the trick. Hence, answer to this question is Html.Raw() but as a variable separate from the model. Please, edit your answer and I will mark it as answer to the question

Comment: To be honest that's not an ideal solution. I'd still suggest defining the property of your model as an `HtmlString` and then using your stringBuilder to populate its value, ie: `public HtmlString Foo {get; set;}` then `Foo = new HtmlString(stringBuilder);`